# Is it possible to pass a list as argument of del?

Tags: python, list

Good morning everybody,

my simple question is the following: I have 2 lists (let's call them *a* and *b*) of length T and I want to eliminate K random elements (with the same index) from each of them.
Let's suppose for the moment K << T, in order to neglect the probability to extract the same index twice or more. Can I simply generate a list *aleaindex* of K random numbers and pass it to *del*, like

```
for i in range(K):
    aleaindex.append(random.randint(0, T-1))
del a[aleaindex]
del b[aleaindex]
```

And is there some Python trick to do this more efficiently?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.

The reason for this is that `del` deletes a name - if there is still another name attached to the object, it will continue to exist. The object itself is untouched.

When you store objects in a list, they do not have names attached, just indices.

This means that when you have a list of objects, Python doesn't know the names that refer to those objects (if there are any), so it can't delete them. It can, at most, remove them from that particular list.

The best solution is to make a new list that doesn't contain the values you don't want. This can be achieved with a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
new_a = [v for i, v in enumerate(a) if i not in aleaindex]
```

You can always assign this back to `a` if you *need* to modify the list (`a[:] = ...`).

Note that it would also make more sense to make `aleaindex` a set, as it would make this operation faster, and the order doesn't matter:

```
aleaindex = {random.randint(0, T-1) for _ in range(K)}
```

Comment: Very interesting answer, thank you very much. Some curiosities: what does the "_" stand for? (I mean, is it just a way not to explicit the - anywhere else useless - name of the loop index?) And why do you say that using sets instead of lists is faster?

Comment: Checking for membership on a set is a much faster operation than checking for membership on a list.

Comment: Sorry @Lattyware but I need a little help with the last line of code you suggested:  why do I get a syntax error when putting it into my code? (the ^ points to the _for_)

Comment: OK, I think to have found out why by myself: it should be aleaindex=(....) instead of aleaindex={....}, isn't it? Thanks

Comment: That would produce a generator, not a set. You must be using a really old version of Python without set comprehensions. Use `aleaindex = set(random.randint(0, T-1) for _ in range(K))` instead.